# Manually select row in UITableView using selectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

So I am trying to pre select the a row in a table using selectRowAtIndexPath.

My question is, where is the best place to call selectRowAtIndexPath?

The only place I thought of calling this, was in cellForRowAtIndexPath:... because I had the indexPath, but that didn't seem to work.

I appreciate any answers or suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` would be one common place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1** :

For the cell to appear selected, you have to call `-setSelected:animated:` from within `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (/* Condition */) {
        [cell setSelected:YES animated:NO];
    }
}
```

**Approach 2** :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

If you want that particular row to be **selected everytime** then **Approach 1** is better, else if you just want it for **selected initially** then **Approach 2** is better.

Comment: Ahh thank you, I approach 2 was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the cell as selected manually, instead of calling the delegate method?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //...
    if( /* some condition */ ) {
        cell.selected = YES;
    }
    //...
    return cell;
}
```